# Java: How to print my array to a text file?

Tags: java, arrays

I've been having trouble trying to get my program to output the array to a text file. I can get the array to print inside the console but when trying to print to the text file I create using PrintWriter. The file doesn't contain anything.

The code is within a method being using in a larger program but I didn't include that because this is the only piece not working currently.

```
try
{
    Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);          
    System.out.print("Enter a odd number value for n:");
    int n = user.nextInt();
        
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Number value must be odd");
    } else {
        Scanner fileName = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter output file name: ");
        String fileNameChoice = fileName.nextLine();
        String outputfilename = fileNameChoice + ".txt";
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(outputfilename);

        int[][] arrayBox = new int[n][n]; //Initializing array here
        int row = n - 1;
        int column = n / 2;
        arrayBox[row][column] = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n * n; i++) { 
        //Loop to set up the array to the sign of the number inputed 
            if (arrayBox[(row + 1) % n][(column + 1) % n] == 0) {
                row = (row + 1) % n;
                column = (column + 1) % n;
            } else {
                row = (row - 1 + n) % n;
            }

            arrayBox[row][column] = i;
        }

            
        for (int i = arrayBox.length-1; i >= n; i--) { 
        //This took way longer than I care to admit 
        // because I did not flip the greater than and less than signs 
        // while wondering why the array was reversed

            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                output.print(arrayBox[i][j] + " "); 
                //Prints the array with a tab space between each of the numbers
            }
                        
            output.println();
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)  
{
    System.out.println("There's an error but I'm not sure how you got here.");
    // Couldn't seem to use PrintWriter without adding this the catch lines, 
    // tried to research but I don't think you'll ever get here
}
```

Comment: You should try to check how you loop through `arrayBox`, the loop doesnt start at all. The PrintWriter code works fine

Comment: This part specifically `for (int i = arrayBox.length-1; i >= n; i--) { `

Comment: I'm confused because when I don't have the code for the PrintWriter, the code comes up fine. It's a list of a perfect square. I assumed I could just add the PrintWriter and it would work. I'm not sure how I would change the loop since it was working before adding PrintWriter. If I change the code to this ```for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)```

It causes the array to print out upside down.

Comment: As Adebayo suggested, you can put the desired output in a String first then write it once you're done processing the loops

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use a PrintWriter? Cause I'd recommend you use a StringBuilder to accumulate the entire array contents first, then use a FileWriter to write to the output file.